# how to prevent a ball from floating over the ground in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an image (ground) with transparent pixels on top of it since the ground has hills like ups and downs ... the problem is that the ball isn't moving down and up according to the hills ... the ball is just floating over the image. what can I do ??

```
local bg2 = display.newImage("images/ground.png",true)
bg2:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
bg2.x = 0; bg2.y = _H/1.25;

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local redOrb = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 25)
redOrb:setFillColor(255,0, 0)
physics.setGravity(0,9.8)
redOrb.x = 180; redOrb.y = 190; redOrb.rotation = 5

physics.addBody( bg2, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
physics.addBody( redOrb, { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a body to an image that has a transparency , it will not automatically make the body the as the image itself.

You can use this tool for the physics body

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

http://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2012/05/24/getting-started-with-coronasdk-and-physicseditor-tutorial

To view the actual physics body you can add this code

```
physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")
```